# Resize integral evaluation limits

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

When I want to show evaluation of limits of an integral, I would type

```
\int_1^2 x\; dx=\frac{x^2}{2}|_1^2=4-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{2}
```

How do I get the vertical bar showing the limits big enough?  I have found `\bigg` and `\Big` but I would like it to autosize like `\left`.  It seems harder because there isn't a left side to figure out what is inside.  I tried `\left<SPACE>` and `\right \mid`, but didn't find success.

Comment: You can use `\left. <stuff> \right|` to autosize a delimiter to the size of <stuff>, e.g.
$$\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_1^2$$
However, this should probably go on the TeX.SE site.

Comment: @Zev: sounds like it should work.  I tried \left (space) <stuff> \right| without success.  Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed something. In these parts the vertical bar is to the **left** of the function. After all, it sort of takes the role of the $\int$ sign. Has there been a change? Is this a geographic thing? Have I lost it?

Comment: There is a vote for deletion of this thread. I object and vote *against* deletion (if there's such a concept). First of all, it has come up from time to time and second, I don't see why closure of this thread is not sufficient to indicate that it is considered off-topic. The answers *are* useful and even if somewhat off-topic I don't understand why it should be removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\left.` and `\right|`

The left/right just has to be matched, but the symbols need not be the same.

```
\[ \int^{2}_{1} x\;dx = \left. \frac{x^{2}}{2}\right|^{2}_{1} = 4 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{7}{2} \]
```

Comment: That's why I tried \left(space) and \right|, but it didn't work.  Maybe \left. works as Zev suggests.

Comment: @Ross Yes, you need the . in order for it to work.

Comment: That's why I tried \left(space) and \right|, but it didn't work.  Maybe \left. works as Zev suggests.  It seems I want \left. and \right| as the vertical comes after the inside.

Comment: @Ross: `\left` must be followed by either a delimiter, or a period that indicates that no delimiter is being used; same with `\right`.

Answer (score 4):

I usually either use manual sizing with some space attached (this can be done with, in increasing order of size, `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`. See below, in the order given, next to the fraction:

```
\[ \frac{x^2}{2}\big|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\Big|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\bigg|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg|; \]
```

To get better spacing, you can use `\bigr` or `\bigm` (or suitably sized).  `\bigl` is used for left delimiters such as `(`, `\bigr` for right delimiters such as `)`, `\bigm` for notation occurring "in the middle" such as `\vert` (which one it is determines the spacing on left and right); this uses `\bigr`, etc:

```
\[ \frac{x^2}{2}\bigr|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\biggr|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\Biggr|; \]
```

and this uses `\bigm`, etc:

```
\[ \frac{x^2}{2}\bigm|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigm|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\biggm|;\qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\Biggm|; \]
```

(note the difference in spacing).

Alternatively, you can use the auto-sizing of `\left` and `\right`. Each one should be followed by a delimiter of some kind, or by a period; a period means that no delimiter is placed; every `\left` must come with a `\right`, and vice-versa, but the sizing is very precise; if you want an oversized bar, you either need to add some vertical phantom  or strut to make `\LaTeX` think your expression is "taller" and/or "deeper". Below I use `\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|`, preceded by `\Bigr` and followed by `\Biggr` for comparison:

```
\[ \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr|;\qquad \left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|; \qquad \frac{x^2}{2}\Biggr|; \]
```

For a bigger one, you can add a "tall" vertical phantom with successive exponents or some other construct; e.g.,

```
\[ \left.\frac{x^2\vphantom{2^{2^{2^2}}}}{2}\right|; \]
```

Comment: `\vphantom` is definitely a good trick to know.

Comment: @Zev: In general, `\vphantom` creates a width-less box with the height of whatever you type; essentially, it creates the vertical space that would be needed to fit what you are typing but doesn't type it. `\hphantom` creates a height-less box with the width of whatever it is you type, leaving the blank horizontal space that would be needed to type it but without typing it.

Comment: @Zev: Mind you, it's probably a very inelegant solution. A more elegant solution would be to construct a box of width $0$ and the desired height and depth using `\makebox`, but this is a quick and dirty way of getting the job done.

Comment: @Zev: Phantom's are dirty tricks used by those of us who learned TeX as PlainTex, and wrote the source code to our dissertations using vi-editor. A nice trick to know, but not very reliable, if you port them to a different place, and (like yours truly) don't really know how TeX works. Chiming what Arturo said: a quick hack.

Comment: @Jyrki: Nice to know I wasn't the only one who wrote their own plain TeX style and macro file for his dissertation on a vi editor! (Though mine was for my undergraduate thesis; there was a ready-made plain TeX one at my graduate institution)... (I also still do my displayed 'formulas by cases' by hand, having learned to do them using The TeXBook).

Answer (score 3):

I think `\bigg\vert` works:

```
\[ \int_1^2 x\ dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg\vert_1^2=4-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{2}.\]
```